# Activity- OnbackPressed issue

Tags: android-listview, onbackpressed

Am launching new `activity` like below

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RetailerHomeActivity.class);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(mIntent);
```

This activity having `listview`, whenever `listview` item click am replacing this `listview` with fragment view.

but after press home button and wait for sometime, if i try to go back activity `listview` by `onbackpress` `listview`, adapters became null

how to avoid this situation.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way , you will not get null.

recall your adapter `onRestart()` in your activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();         
            GetListData();   // call your adapter here or set data of listview  here too                   
    }
```